# What is WebViewControlProcess? And how to use this in webview?

Tags: wpf, windows, webview, uwp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.ui.interop.webviewcontrolprocess?view=winrt-19041

If anyone has the github demo. Please let me know.

Comment: Could you please tell me why do you want to use the WebViewControlProcess class?

Comment: I am exploring some solutions to create the webview in a separate process. Because Currently UWP webview holds a chunk of memory and  I want to free up full webview memory.

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` control provides ways to create `WebView` in a separate process. You could check this method-[WebView(WebViewExecutionMode)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.-ctor?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebView__ctor_Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_WebViewExecutionMode_). You just need to set the `WebViewExecutionMode.SeparateProcess` as parameter.

Comment: Already tried this solution. This won't solve the memory retain problem. WebView keeps consuming the memory. I want a solution like chrome where it creates a new tab/webivew in separate process and kills the process on tab close.

Comment: You have to set the WebView source to Null if you want to clean the WebView memory.

Comment: Can you please create an app with webview and load any URL and make it null. See if you are able to clean the memory.

Comment: Let me confirm one thing first, are you developing a UWP project?